# Windows Phone App (Creating a Project) in VS 2017

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I recently installed VS 2017 community and am unable to find any option to create a "blank windows phone app" project. Yes I have Xamarin installed (Along with the emulators). Has it been removed since Windows phone app development is included via UWP (Universal Apps) project option? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is not supported any more. You can find it for example [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15320/windows-phone-81-not-supported.html)

> The Visual Studio team has determined that this issue is not a bug. Unfortunately, the Cordova tools in VS 2017 does not support Windows 8.1 development.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response! does it mean I'm limited in any way if I want to develop apps for Windows phone (from scratch) since I can still do it via UWP Project? Thanks!

Comment: @DarkInferno Visual Studio 2017 doesn't support projects for old WinPhone versions like 8.1 and earlier. But you can freely use UWP app project and it will work with Windows Phone 10.

Comment: Alright...and after a quick search it seems the older SDKs aren't supported on Windows 10 either.....Welp, guess its time to screw the old ones and just build on the latest platform. Thanks again

Comment: @DarkInferno Yes it sounds like a good solution. But as a benefit you can use the same UWP binary for both WinPhone 10 and Windows 10 desktop. And if remove WinPhone 8.1 support from your Xamarin library it will support more API. For example If you use [.NetStandart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) you can use version up to 1.4